# Line extraction with java code

Tags: java, extract

i have this code that read from  a log files and extract the line that contains the word  password and write it done in an other file but instead of extracting just that line  it extract the hole line . if you can help me to see where did i go wrong thank you

this is my code :

```
package logins;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class extract_log {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File dir = new File("d:/Userfiles/arafei/Desktop/pd_files");
        BufferedReader bf;
        FileReader fr = null;
        File f;
        File f2 = new File("d:/Userfiles/arafei/Desktop/pd_files/output.log");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f2);
        if(dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] fichiers = dir.list();
            for(int j = 0; j<fichiers.length; j++) {
                if(! new File("d:/Userfiles/arafei/Desktop/pd_files/" + fichiers[j]).isDirectory() ) {
                    f= new File("d:/Userfiles/arafei/Desktop/pd_files/" + fichiers[j]);
                    fr = new FileReader(f);
                    bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null){
                        if(!line.toLowerCase().contains("password *") && !line.toLowerCase().contains("password none") ){
                            System.out.println(line);
                            fw.write(line + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fw.close();
        fr.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: you are writing whole line that's the reason its writing whole line in new file.

Comment: in fact i have a txt file that contains  lines and some lines have the word password  i need to extract just that line  , what the code do is that extract every thing

Comment: I think that you are writing down every line that **does not** contain `password`

Comment: in the line that i extract there is the word password  but it is not just the line but the hole contains of the txt

Comment: @Plirkee, _contains()_ is literal so he's looking for all lines that **don't** contain "password *" and "password none".

Comment: You should provide sample input, your output and expected output

Comment: I agree with Plirkee, I still don't understand what's the problem as your sentence is a contradiction "instead of extracting just that line it extracts the hole line"

Comment: like for example i have thoes lines
03/08/2016;13:10:38.454; password for user is......................
03/08/2016;13:10:38.454; The arranger is arranging for
03/08/2016;13:10:38.719;AERGO;
03/08/2016;13:10:38.455; password is ....................................
03/08/2016;13:10:38.457; password * not in the......................
i need the code to show me just the first line and the 3 line but instead it extract the all four lines

Comment: @mateos add some sample input and expected output .

Comment: i have just add some example the dates is the start of the lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using streams and nio:

```
Path dir = Paths.get("d:/Userfiles/arafei/Desktop/pd_files");
Path out = Paths.get("d:/Userfiles/arafei/Desktop/pd_files/output.log");

if(Files.isDirectory(dir)) {
    List<Path> files = Files.list(dir)
        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<String> outLines = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Path p : files) {
        Files.readAllLines(p)
            .stream()
            .filter(line -> 
                line.toLowerCase().contains("password")
                && !line.toLowerCase().contains("password *")
                && !line.toLowerCase().contains("password none")
            )
            .forEach(outLines::add);
    }
    Files.write(out, outLines);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your if from

```
if(!line.toLowerCase().contains("password *") && !line.toLowerCase().contains("password none") )
```

to

```
if(line.toLowerCase().contains("password"))
```

Comment: in fact it will extract even the exceptions :/

Answer (score 0):

hey guys i needed just to add some little stuff in the code and the logic

```
if(line.toLowerCase().contains("password") &&
!line.toLowerCase().contains("password *") && !line.toLowerCase().contains("password none") ){
                            System.out.println(line);
                            fw.write(line + "\n\n");
```

that was it , thank you all